# Sql server is not loading in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have installed my sql server in a Virtual machine and I tried to connect(`menu->tools->connect to database`) that sql server to my visual studio which is installed in my local computer but server name is not showing in there and I also tried to add server name manually but then the databases are not showing(Both VM and the local computer are in the same internet connection). What is the solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You must open `1433` port in your firewall and start `SQL Server Browser` service in `SQL Server Configuration Manager`

Comment: tell him how and why

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: And you have to make sure, remote access is enabled. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I entered server name from the visual studio but when I tried to load databases It shows "Login failed for user ..." what is the problem